# Phalcon: setStatusCode returns empty response

Tags: php, phalcon

I'm trying to write error handling for one of the endpoints in phalcon.

If I set status code to client/server error code(4xx/5xx), then the response returned is empty. How can I fix that?

Example:

```
$test = [
    "test message"
];

$response->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    ->setStatusCode(200)
    ->setJsonContent($test)
    ->send();
```

In browser network tab, I get this as response (which is completely fine)

```
["test message"]
```

but if I just change the statusCode to say, 500

```
    ->setStatusCode(500)
```

I get empty response

Comment: i just tried it with chrome's fetch and i got response. ```fetch('').then((res) => res.json()).then((s) => console.log(s))```

Comment: try using [post man](https://www.postman.com/) also

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following line,

```
setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
```